# MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail returns false if the email account was added via a profile (like MDM)

Tags: ios, swift, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

a customer reported an error that a lot of users could not send email because they only got an alert that there is no email account.
The alert is done in code if `MFMailComposeViewController` returns `false` from `canSendMail`.

We had difficulty finding out what the real problem was, but after some testing we found out, that `canSendMail` always returns `false` when the only email account available is setup via a profile (possibly MDM or something like the Apple Configurator).

The configured email has no problem receiving and sending emails in Mail itself and when it is added manually without a profile, it works as expected.

Has anyone any suggestion or a possible workaround? Maybe it is just a misconfiguration?
[image]

Comment: Basically MFMailconposer works on your email id which is added to your phone's setting , So i think that it wont added through your app. I think but not sure

Comment: I am also having this issue, may be because now you can delete default Mail app with iOS 10, so it's returning false every time, have you solved it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a solution yet either.

Comment: Do you have solution to this problem ?

Comment: Reported it as a bug but the status is still on open, so no change yet